# How to add an Image on a Frame in the Racket GUI Toolkit?

Tags: user-interface, racket

How can one add an image (for example png) onto a frame% object?

```
#lang racket
(define my-frame (new frame%))
;want to add an image to my-frame
```

Comment: This is #racket, this has nothing to do with #scheme.  Please do not mix the things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [a canvas](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/windowing-overview.html#%28part._canvas-drawing%29).

```
(define my-frame (new frame%
                      [label "Example"]
                      [width 300]
                      [height 300]))

(new canvas% 
     [parent my-frame]
     [paint-callback
      (λ (canvas dc)
        (send dc draw-bitmap (read-bitmap "/path/to/image.png") 0 0))])

(send my-frame show #t)
```